# Hibernate criteria not working for two values in same table using Restrictions.neProperty() specifically for null value?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to get objects using hibernate criteria in one of the table. I have to add one criterion for two columns in the same table whose values should not be equal. So I added the following line into existing criteria:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.neProperty("column1", "column2"));
```

But above does not seem to work,

I tried a few things, added same long values in both the columns & changed condition to,

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("column1", "column2"));
```

It worked well, I then edited the values to be unequal instead of one being null, changed criteria to,

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.neProperty("column1", "column2"));
```

Above also worked, But when I have `column1` a valid value & `column2` null then above criteria is failing, What might be the cause?

Comment: because in SQL `value = null` does not work. for `null` checks you need `value is null` or `value is not null` for `value != null`. So you would need to work in `Restrictions#isNotNull(String property)` or `Restrictions#isNull(String property)`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer whatever you are saying seems true based on my trials with null data values, I thought null will be treated as unequal, Thanks